# Java Regex missing a match in the output

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am currently matching a string against a regular expression. My pattern is:

```
"(?<=\p{Alnum}|\p{Punct})(\p{Alnum}+\p{Punct}{1})"
```

I am matching it with the string:

```
"https://www.google.com/"
```

My desired result with the above regex and string is:

```
https:, www., google., com/
```

I am able to get all the matches successfully except 'https:' one. In that case it is giving out 'ttps:' instead of the required 'https:'

I am not able to understand where I went wrong. Can anyone please help me in figuring this out?

Comment: check your Regex here {https://regex101.com/}, you'll see it does not match your string

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have just checked it again on the same site. It is giving me 4 matches. 3 of them were right, but the 'ttps:' one is wrongs as my required match in that case is 'https:'

Comment: Do you want `(?<![^\p{Alnum}\p{Punct}])(\p{Alnum}+\p{Punct})`? Like [here](https://regex101.com/r/MzHRuR/1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<![^\p{Alnum}\p{Punct}])(\p{Alnum}+\p{Punct})
```

See the [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MzHRuR/1).

The `(?<![^\p{Alnum}\p{Punct}])` *negative* lookbehind matches a location that is not immediately preceded by a char other than an alphanumeric and a punctuation char.

Note that your regex required an alphanumeric or punctuation char immediately on the left, so it was impossible to match the start of string position.

Note that `{1}` is always redundant, you can see more about regex redundancy in the ["Writing cleaner regular expressions" YT video of mine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efsvvVob4Ok).